# Completely different question marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, reopen-request, closed-questions, duplicates

I asked a [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/190001/social-skills-and-knuckle-punching-at-work) about social skills. This question cites my previous question for reference purposes. But it's completely different from my previous because the nature of the question is completely different. My previous question was about handling a particular situation at work. The other one is about workplace social skills.

Yet my latter question was marked as duplicate. I don't understand why two completely different questions would be viewed as the same. I'd appreciate some help with clarification.

Comment: I read the latter and the question you are asking is *"do I lack basic social skills?"* which is something we can't answer (not saying that you don't have social skills hehe, just saying that we can't give you a yes/no via a site on the internet). Even if we gave you a yes/no answer to that it would serve no goal or purpose. I also read the former question which I found interesting and saw you got helpful answers, and also think that the latter one was an opinion-based rephrased derivate-ish from the former.

Answer (score 3):

As I explained in my comment on that question when I closed it I agree it's not (strictly speaking) a duplicate of the first question - but that it appears to be about answers you got to that question when you asked it on the Norwegian forum you mention. And asking users here to chime in on whether they think the users there were correct doesn't really work as a question.

If we strip away all the connections to the other question and the Norwegian forums then it becomes

> If I don't respond promptly do I lack basic social skills?

Which is an opinion-based yes/no question that would almost certainly be closed as lacking a goal for us to address. If you changed it to:

> How can I obtain the social skills to handle this sort of situation promptly?

Then it's a pretty broad intrapersonal skills question that's probably too broad to address here and not workplace specific. If you reworked it into:

> What is the appropriate response to this situation in the workplace?

it comes full circle back to being a duplicate of the first question. Ultimately that is why I went with the call to close it as a duplicate - because the only on-topic version I could get to ended up being one.

Answer (score 0):

Neutral 3rd party observer here.

Firstly, I agree the question should be closed. I'm not entirely sure that as a Duplicate was *strictly* the right reason, but I see why it was chosen.

The question stems from the same incident - the meta-answer (heh pun intended) to both questions could be considered so similar as to make the questions essentially duplicate.

What I mean is - if you ask 'what is 2x2' and 'what is 6-2' - They are both different questions - but since the answer is 4, they are functionally the same.

People advising how to be more assertive or disagreeable or how to professionally set clear boundaries is the answer to both questions.

So even though the questions are different, the functional answers are the same.

Now, if I were to distinguish the latest question from your original, there is a unique question that I think you've asked...

But as pointed out in the comments, the Interpersonal SE is the right location for *that* question, not WP SE.

That's my take on it: I see the reason why it was closed, agree it should be closed, have a minor quibble on the reasoning - but think it was valid.